# I trial get all comments for Post and add user in NotfFaId ,

Tags: python, django, model

I trial get all comments for Post and add user in NotfFaId I don't understand how fix it. ,
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

```
def topic_single(request, post):

    post = get_object_or_404(Topic, slug=post, status='published')
    postcat = Topic.objects.filter(category=post.category)
    # print(post.comments.all())

    fav = bool
    random_items = Topic.newmanager.all().order_by('?')[0:9]

    if post.favourites.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        fav = True
 
    session_key = 'view_post_{}'.format(post)
    if not request.session.get(session_key,False):
        post.views +=1
        post.save()
        request.session[session_key] = True
    
    allcomments = post.comments.filter(status=True)

    CommentT.objects.get(id=allcomments).NotfFaId.add(request.user)


    comment_form = NewCommentTForm()

    return render(request, 'forum/detail.html', {'post': post, 'comment_form': comment_form, 'allcomments': allcomments,
    'random_items': random_items,
    'Category': Category.objects.all(),'Category2': postcat, 
    'fav': fav})
```

model

```
class CommentT(MPTTModel):
    Topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey( User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
    NotfFaId = models.ManyToManyField( User, related_name='NotfFaVId', default=None, blank=True)
   
    content = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['publish']
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it

```
def topic_single(request, post):

    post = get_object_or_404(Topic, slug=post, status='published')
    postcat = Topic.objects.filter(category=post.category)
    # print(post.comments.all())

    fav = bool
    random_items = Topic.newmanager.all().order_by('?')[0:9]

    if post.favourites.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        fav = True
 
    session_key = 'view_post_{}'.format(post)
    if not request.session.get(session_key,False):
        post.views +=1
        post.save()
        request.session[session_key] = True
    
    allcomments = post.comments.filter(status=True)
    for e in allcomments:
        CommentT.objects.get(id=e.pk).NotfFaId.add(request.user)


    comment_form = NewCommentTForm()

    return render(request, 'forum/detail.html', {'post': post, 'comment_form': comment_form, 'allcomments': allcomments,
    'random_items': random_items,
    'Category': Category.objects.all(),'Category2': postcat, 
    'fav': fav})
```